# Column Value Does Not Show In Select

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I need help with my code, I can't figure out what's wrong with it. I want the selection to display a column from table based on an id.

The problem is with this code:

```sql
SELECT * FROM tbl_topic WHERE course_code = :cid
```

The select works only when I use `SELECT * FROM tbl_topic`. Can anyone point out what is wrong in my code?

```
<select class="form-control" width="auto" name="tname" id="tname">
    <?php
        try {
            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_topic WHERE course_code = :cid");
            $stmt->execute();
            $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
        }
        catch(PDOException $e){
            echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
        foreach($result as $topicrow) {
        ?>
            <?php if((isset($_GET['edit'])) && ($editrow['topic_name']==$topicrow['topic_name'])) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $topicrow['topic_name']; ?>" selected><?php echo $topicrow['topic_name'];?></option>
            <?php } else { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $topicrow['topic_name']; ?>"><?php echo $topicrow['topic_name'];?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        <?php
        } // while
        $conn = null;
    ?> 
</select>
```

Comment: What error do you get? What do you get if you manually run the query? You aren't binding anything to cid. http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Answer (score 1):

You don't bind the parameter `:cid`! You can use [`bindParam`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) to solve this:

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_topic WHERE course_code = :cid");

//bind paramter :cid here...
$stmt->bindParam(':cid', $cid_value, PDO::PARAM_INT);

$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```